# Overlapping Overlay Image with Image Taken from camera

Tags: android

I am doing a project where I need to OverLay few custom images, where option to add faces taken from camera will be given. Considering the following image
 [image: overlayImage]

I will take faces from camera and I want to fit in the face into this overlay.

I have used following layout structure

- FrameLayout
- SurfaceView // For Displaying custom Camera
- ImageView  // For Displaying The overlay image as below
- FrameLayout

I have zoom option for the ImageView as well which will make the image to fit in the Faces taken from camera

Now I am stuck in following 2 problems:

1. When I click on take picture, I am trying to get the drawing cache
   of the `Framelayout`, But I am getting a black image for the
   surfaceview view
2. Since I have `ImageView` to be zoomed as well, I am not able to
   stitch back overlay to fit the face taken